# Automatically match and replace word & position with its replacement

Tags: r, regex, replace, google-analytics, gsub

I am working with Google Analytics conversion path data in R. My imported data frame looks like the following example:

```
    Channel_Path                                | Source_Path
Social > Email > Social > Paid Search > Social  | facebook > mailtool > m.facebook.com > google > facebook+instagram
Organic Search > Email > Social                 | google > mailtool > pinterest
```

As you can see, the different channels are separated by a ">" symbol. What I would like to do is the following:

Replace "Social" in the "Channel_Path" column by the corresponding value in the "Source_Path" column without changing any other values. This should happen to all rows in the dataset.

The result should then look like the following:

```
      Channel_Path                                                   | Source_Path
facebook > Email > m.facebook.com > Paid Search > facebook+instagram | facebook > mailtool > m.facebook.com > google > facebook+instagram
Organic Search > Email > pinterest                                   | google > mailtool > pinterest
```

The issue I have here is that I am working with a large dataset (60.000 rows) and that I don't know how to automatically replace the values depending on their position.

For a better reproducability, here is the code for the example given above:

```
df <- data.frame(Channel_Path = c("Social > Email > Social > Paid Search > Social", "Organic Search > Email > Social"),
             Source_Path = c("facebook > mailtool > m.facebook.com > google > facebook+instagram", "google > mailtool > pinterest"))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the data in long format separating the columns on `" > "`, replace `Channel_Path` values where `Channel_Path == 'Social'` and paste the values again.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(Channel_Path, Source_Path, sep = " > ") %>%
  mutate(Channel_Path = ifelse(Channel_Path == 'Social', 
                               Source_Path, Channel_Path)) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  summarise(across(.fns = ~paste(., collapse = " > "))) %>%
  select(-row) 

#                                                          Channel_Path
#1 facebook > Email > m.facebook.com > Paid Search > facebook+instagram
#2                                   Organic Search > Email > pinterest
#                                                         Source_Path
#1 facebook > mailtool > m.facebook.com > google > facebook+instagram
#2                                      google > mailtool > pinterest
```

Comment: Hey @Ronak, this is very helpful! One slight adaption/Question: i have two more columns with the conversions and the conversion-value. After executing your code, those are grouped with the ">" as well. In other words: instead of having a conversion value of  600, i get 600 > 600 > 600. Is there a way to avoid that this happens for other columns? Thank you!

Comment: @emil_rore I guess you can change the `summarise` line to `summarise(across(c(Channel_Path, Source_Path), .fns = ~paste(., collapse = " > ")))` so only those two columns are changed.

Comment: Hey Ronak, Thanks a lot! Yeah, you are right - this changes only those two columns  but also leaves only those two columns in the "df". Do you know if there are any issues with using "conversion = first(conversion)" within the summarse line to add the unchanged values to the end table?

Comment: Yes, you can use that in `summarise`. Alternatively, you can use those columns in `group_by` as well.

Answer (score 0):

input:

```
df <- data.frame(Channel_Path = c("Social > Email > Social > Paid Search > Social", "Organic Search > Email > Social"),
         Source_Path = c("facebook > mailtool > m.facebook.com > google > facebook+instagram", "google > mailtool > pinterest"))
```

function:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

google_analytics <- function(col1,col2){
str1 <- str_split(col1," > ")[[1]]
str2 <- str_split(col2," > ")[[1]]
result <- ""
for(i in 1:length(str1)){
  if(str1[i]=="Social"){
    str1[i] <- ifelse(str2[i] %in% c("facebook+instagram","m.facebook.com"),"facebook",str2[i])
  }
  if(i==length(str1)){
    result <- paste0(result, str1[i])
    next
  }
  result <- paste0(result, str1[i], " > ")
}

return(result)
}

df <- df %>% rowwise() %>% dplyr::mutate(Channel_Path=google_analytics(Channel_Path,Source_Path))
```

output:

```
Channel_Path                                   Source_Path                                             
  <chr>                                          <chr>                                                   
1 facebook > Email > facebook > Paid Search > f~ facebook > mailtool > m.facebook.com > google > faceboo~
2 Organic Search > Email > pinterest             google > mailtool > pinterest
```

Comment: Hey @Flo - unfortunately, this does not give me the desired output on my real dataset. As mentioned in my comment, my code was just a sample to make it reproducible. However, my real dataset consists of 60.000 rows and the code does not automatically match the position of the word Social with the corresponding replacement.

Comment: Ok i've edited my code to try something a bit different.

Comment: Hey Flo, thanks again for trying! Untortunately, this code replaces all values in column "Channel_Path" with the value that I have in the first row of my dataset. Now all rows have the value "Paid Search".

Comment: I have extended my example by one line - maybe it's then easier to reproduce when another line is added to the dataframe

Comment: My bad, i've forgotten the command rowwise() to split the data line by line before applying the function. Hope it's working as intended now.

Answer (score 0):

We will work row by row and for each row we'll parse the elements of each column using `scan()`, then we'll use `ifelse()` to get a vector of the right element, that we'll collapse back into our requested output.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate_at("Channel_Path", ~{
    cp <- scan(text = ., what = character(), sep = ">", strip.white = TRUE, quiet = TRUE)
    sp <- scan(text = Source_Path, what = character(), sep = ">", strip.white = TRUE, quiet = TRUE)
    cp <- ifelse(cp == "Social", sp, cp)
    paste(cp, collapse = " > ")
  }) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   Channel_Path                             Source_Path                          
#>   <chr>                                    <chr>                                
#> 1 facebook > Email > m.facebook.com > Pai~ facebook > mailtool > m.facebook.com~
#> 2 Organic Search > Email > pinterest       google > mailtool > pinterest
```